# libjitsi PCMA (ALAW) decoder

Tags: jitsi

I am using libjitsi for G.711 encode/decode. For PCMU it is fine, however, for PCMA, there is only encoder available. Why is the decoder not supported?

http://bluejimp.com/jitsi/libjitsi/javadoc/org/jitsi/impl/neomedia/codec/audio/alaw/package-summary.html

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to create a decoder for pcma/alaw using the pcmu/ulaw decoder as an example; I'll actually be creating one myself in the next few weeks for an internal company project.

Comment: Thanks. I did create my own at last, was wondering is there any particular reason that it is not there.

Comment: My assumption is that no one requested it and no one on the team needed one.